# In Darkest Hour, what was the sound each time the date changed?

Tags: sound-effects, darkest-hour

In *Darkest Hour*, several times the date appears onscreen as a graphic, and it switches from one date to another. The change is accompanied by the sound of an egg timer's "ping", and then a heavy mechanical sound. What are these sounds supposed to be, and why were they used?

**EDIT**

The first instance of this happens at 5:25 (starting from when the "Focus Features" logo appears onscreen).

[image]

Comment: To ensure the audience remained awake? I do recall what you're talking about and I just understood it to be a time change signifier. Having said that, I may have to watch it again.

Comment: Thanks Brett - couldn't say for certain, but it sounds like the chime mechanism of a big clock starting up [the Westminster clock/Big Ben would seem apropos] - aside from the tiny ding at the start, which I assume has more to do with the scene we're watching than the 'impending doom' hinted by the large 'slide, kerthunk'... [unless they all have that ding... but I haven't seen the whole movie yet - probably tomorrow, it's in the queue for]